# Wordpress: remove un-wanted html tag from WP REST API JSON file

Tags: php, html, json, wordpress, rest

I am new to Wordpress, and using WP REST API to get JSON data to be used in another project. However, inside the JSON data, there are some adjustment I want to make so that it's easy to use these data. For example, in `excerpt.rendered` section, I just want pure words, without additional `<p>` or `\n` or `</p>` and other html tags.

[image]

I know this may have something with the php document, but I am new to WP, so which file I need to make some changes so that I get the excerpt as I want?

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively straightforward way to to this.

To remove the wrapping `<p>` tags from excerpts, put the following line in your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
```

To remove the wrapping tags from the content:

```
remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

More details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter/

If there are other HTML tags you want to remove that are automatically being added, see if there is a related filter you can disable. Otherwise you'll have to update your PHP routes to manually remove the offending HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `<WebView/>` for display content. WebView displays content with hiding HTML tag.

Comment: WebView is part of React Native so it is not always possible solution.

Answer (score -3):

Can't you just use strip_tags before returning your response to the other project?

i.e

```
$excerpt = $json[excerpt][rendered];
return strip_tags($excerpt);
```

This should remove all HTML tags and entities and return just the raw content.

Alternatively, if you need the whole JSON response, I **imagine** stripping the tags before the excerpt is serialised should work.

Try replacing:

```
/**
 * Check the post excerpt and prepare it for single post output.
 *
 * @param string       $excerpt
 * @return string|null $excerpt
 */
protected function prepare_excerpt_response( $excerpt ) {
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        return __( 'There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.' );
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
    $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $excerpt ) );

    if ( empty( $excerpt ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $excerpt;
}
```

With:

```
/**
 * Check the post excerpt and prepare it for single post output.
 *
 * @param string       $excerpt
 * @return string|null $excerpt
 */
protected function prepare_excerpt_response( $excerpt ) {
    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        return __( 'There is no excerpt because this is a protected post.' );
    }

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
    $excerpt = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $excerpt ) );

    if ( empty( $excerpt ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    return strip_tags($excerpt);
}
```

in **class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php** *Line 651*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my folder, I don't have "class-wp-json-posts.php" file. I am using WP REST API V2. do you know how to implement this in this plugin? thanks

Comment: @LeoGuo - Apologies, I got the wrong plugin, see updated answer. The same logic applies. Although I haven't used the plugin, it would appear from the code that you should already be getting a 'raw' response as well as the rendered one when it gets the excerpt?

Comment: @LeoGuo    See:

`if ( ! empty( $schema['properties']['excerpt'] ) ) {
   $data['excerpt'] = array(
    'raw'      => $post->post_excerpt,
    'rendered' => $this->prepare_excerpt_response( $post->post_excerpt ),
   );
  }`

That looks to me to be adding a raw value before serialisation anyway?

Comment: This should be done by hooking rest api events, NOT modifying core WP files!